# Unbound Error when having two Django forms in a single HTML page

Tags: python, html, django

I have created a simple ToDo List app using Django. Recently I have worked on adding Due Dates to each task/todo. It works fine too. But to add a due date to any task, users will have to go to another URL and then add the date. What I want to do is have a due date Django form right in the Home page below every single task. When I try to accomplish this, I was successfully able to show the due form below each task, but when I input a day and press enter, Django throws an Unbound Local Error. The two forms I am having on my single Home page are the `todo_form` which is a single input field that is used to create new todos on the Home page and this `due_form` that will handle Due Dates.

This is my views.py `home` function

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "due_form" in request.POST:
            due_form = DueDateForm(request.POST)

            if due_form.is_valid():
                days = due_form.cleaned_data.get("due_date")

                if days == "today":
                    days = 0
                elif days == "tomorrow":
                    days = 1
                elif days == "next week":
                    days = 7
                elif days == "yesterday":
                    days = -1
                elif days == "last week":
                    days = -7
                else:
                    days = int(days)

                today = datetime.datetime.today()
                due_date = today + datetime.timedelta(days=days)

                todo = ToDo.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST.get("id")))
                todo.due_date = due_date
                todo.save()

                messages.success(request, "Due Date added to task")

                return redirect("todo-home")

            add_form = NewTaskForm()

        elif "add_form" in request.POST:
            add_form = NewTaskForm(request.POST)

            if add_form.is_valid():
                title = add_form.cleaned_data.get("title")
                todo = ToDo(title=title)
                todo.creator = request.user
                todo.save()

                user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
                user.profile.todos += 1
                user.save()
                messages.success(request, "Your new task has been added")

                return redirect("todo-home")

            due_form = DueDateForm()

    else:
        add_form = NewTaskForm()
        due_form = DueDateForm()

    todos = ToDo.objects.all()

    context = {
        "todos": todos,
        "add_form": add_form, # This is line 98 (that is, where the error occured)
        "due_form": due_form
    }

    return render(request, "ToDo/home.html", context=context)
```

Parts of my home.html that's relevant

```
<!-- The "todo_form" that handles new tasks -->
<div class="content section">
    <form method="POST" name="add_form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group dark-mode-assist">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New ToDo!</legend>
            {{ add_form|crispy }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit" name="add-task">Add</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
.
. { some HTML code that handles task title and other meta data }
.
<!-- This is the "due_form" -->
<div class="content section">
    <form method="POST" name="due_form" id={{ todo.pk }}>
       {% csrf_token %}
       <fieldset class="form-group dark-mode-assist">
          <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Due in (days)</legend>
          {{ due_form|crispy }}
       </fieldset>
       <div class="form-group">
           <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add</button>
        </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

This is the error I am seeing
[image: My error details about the UnboundLocalError]

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this don't end with:

```
else:
    add_form = NewTaskForm()
    due_form = DueDateForm()
```

Instead before your first if statement, default those variables.

```
add_form = NewTaskForm()
due_form = DueDateForm()
if ...:
    ...
```